# Как вызвать метод одного класса в другом классе

Tags: java, многопоточность, методы

(Как вызвать метод класса(1) в классе(2))

Вроде для этого нужно создать объект класса(1) в классе(2), однако уже на этом этапе возникает ошибка

```
java: constructor Integral in class Integral cannot be applied to given types;
  required: Function,double,double,double
  found:    no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

...
Вообще программа должна считать определенный интеграл с заданным числом потоков, так что теперь нужно в классе T вызвать метод calc() с уже известными параметрами

```
    double a = 0;
    double b = Math.PI;
    double interval = b - a;
    double h = Math.pow(10, -7);
```

Прошу помощи в том как это сделать

Класс 1

```
public class Integral {

    private Function function;

    private double a;
    private double b;

    private double h;

    public Integral(Function function, double a, double b, double h) {
        this.function = function;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.h = h;
    }

    public double calc() {
        double sum = 0;
        for(double x = a+h; x <= b-h; x+=h) {
            sum += 2*function.fun(x);
        }
        sum += function.fun(a);
        sum += function.fun(b);
        return sum*h/2;
    }
}
```

Класс 2

```
public class T extends Thread {
   // private Integral sum;
    Integral in = new Integral(); //создаю объект класса, на который ругается компилятор

    double a = 0;
    double b = Math.PI;
    double interval = b - a;
    double h = Math.pow(10, -7);
    private double threads;
    double step = interval / threads;
    double x;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Выполнен поток " + getName()+" "  );

        for ( int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {


        }


}}
```

.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите количество потоков(1-10)");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            T thread = new T();
            thread.start();
        }

    }
}
```

.

```
public interface Function {

    public double fun(double x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс Integral содержит конструктор с параметрами. Вы их не передаете, поэтому возникает ошибка при создании объекта. Либо передавайте параметры при создании объекта, либо создайте пустой конструктор и передавайте параметры уже непосредственно в метод, соответственно надо его параметризировать -

```
    public double calc(Function function, double a, double b, double h){
    .....
}
```